# Javascript Loop through and Concatenate 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to loop through and concatenate 2 arrays such as below, I don’t know how many values there will be as a user could purchase 1 or 100 products so it needs to loop.

```
Array1 = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']

Array2 = ['123', '45', '6789',]
```

I need to output to be:

```
ABC:123|DEF:45|GHI:6789
```

Currently code I have...

```
function() {
  var array_one = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'];
  var array_two = ['179.99', '349.99', '399.99', '389'];
  for (var i = 0; i < array_one.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array_two.length; j++) {
      return(array_one[i] + ":" + array_two[j] + "|");
    }
  }
}
```

This only outputs one value and doesn't loop through, any ideas where my loop is breaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This only outputs one value and doesn't loop through, any ideas
>   where my loop is breaking.

**what is the cause ?**

It's only returning one value because you're using the `return` keyword within the first iteration hence it will exit within the first iteration.

**where does the error occur ?**

the code below is where your loop is breaking:

```
 return(array_one[i] + ":" + array_two[j] + "|");
```

**How to resolve the issue ?**

`Note` : you don't actually need a nested loop in this case because both arrays have the same length so we can simplify it.

in order to improve your current solution we can make a string variable and append the result there such as:

```
function() {
  var array_one = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'];
  var array_two = ['179.99', '349.99', '399.99', '389'];
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < array_one.length; i++) {
     result += array_one[i] + ":" + array_two[i] + "|";
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I just added a result = result.slice(0,-1) to remove the final unused '|' symbol. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that both arrays have the same length then simple map would be enough:

```js
var array1 = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
var array2 = ['123', '45', '6789']

var result = array1.map(function(item, index) {
  return item + ':' + array2[index]
}).join('|')

console.log(result)
```

Or a ES2015 version:

```
var result = array1.map((item, index) => `${item}:${array2[index]}`).join('|')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is little wrong, you don't really need two loops. With one loop you can do it and you shouldn't return inside the loop.

Since they are of the same size, below code should do

```
var result="";
for (var i = 0; i < array_one.length; i++) {     
     result += (array_one[i] + ":" + array_two[i] + "|");    
}
return result;
```

Comment: Should `array_two[2]` be `array_two[i]`?

Comment: @Rajesh Ahh, my bad. Corrected. Thankyou

Comment: Another corrrection, you are adding `"|"` every time. It should not happen for last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to add elements from `array_two` and then `join()` to create string.

```js
var array_one = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'];
var array_two = ['179.99', '349.99', '399.99', '389'];

var result = array_one.map(function(e, i) {
  return e + ':' + array_two[i]
}).join('|')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce`

```js
var array_one = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'];
var array_two = ['179.99', '349.99', '399.99', '389'];

var result = array_one.reduce(function(p, c, i, a) {
  p += c + ":" + array_two[i]
  if (i < a.length - 1)
    p+="|"
  return p;
}, "")

console.log(result)
```

---

#### With for loop

```js
var array_one = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'];
var array_two = ['179.99', '349.99', '399.99', '389'];

var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i< array_one.length; i++){
  result += array_one[i] + ":" + array_two[i]
  if (i < array_one.length - 1)
    result += "|"
}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr1 = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'],
    arr2 = ['123', '45', '6789'],
    result = '';
    
    //iterate over every element from arr1 and add it into the 
    //result string with corresponding value from arr2
    arr1.forEach((v,i) => result += v + ':' + arr2[i] + '|'); 
    console.log(result.slice(0, -1)); //cut the `|` sign from the end of the string
```

Answer (score -1):

Just one 'for loop'  is enough for the output you want

```
     var  returnValue = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < array_one.length; i++)
        {
        returnValue+ =array_one[i] + ":" + array_two[j] + "|";
        }
     return  returnValue;
```